# Inequalities and logarithm

Tags: inequality, logarithms, curves

If $f(x) = k^3x + k^3 – 2$ cuts the curve $g(x) = \frac{1}{2}ln(x)^2$ at exactly one point then What interval would 'k' belong to ?

I basically tried to equate both the equations together but got stuck. Any ideas ?

EDIT: Edited the question.

Comment: do you mean $$\ln(x^2)$$ or $$(\ln(x))^2$$?

Comment: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/1zxye1ubps

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner  Thanks for pointing out, I have edited the question.